# Importing an overloaded function in PascalScript

Tags: delphi, overloading, pascalscript

How can I be sure that PascalScript import the right function (using **AddFunction()**) considering that the function is overloaded ?

For exmaple I want to import system.Random.
In the EngineCompile event I add this:

```
AddFunction( @System.Random, 'function Random: Extended;' );
```

But when testing a script which calls *random*, I always get **NAN** as result.

My test script is

```
Program Script;
Var
  a: Single;
  Check: String;
Begin
  a := Random;
  Check := FloatToStr(a);
  ShowMessage(Check);
End.
```

I have the strong feeling that PascalScript imports the other version of **random**.
What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint on each of the possible overloads (in *System.pas*, for this particular case). Execute your script. See which one the debugger stops at.

Comment: I've made a function call to the right version with another name and then it has suddently worked. What is interesting here, in a general way, is that making a procedure pointer to an overloaded function always return the first function declared...I wonder if there is another way to force the compiler to use one or the other version of the function?

Comment: I don't know what "the right version with another name" means. `System.Random` has only one name. You can use different names in your script, but that won't affect what the expression `@System.Random` resolves to within Delphi.

Comment: I just mean that @System.Random always returns a pointer to *Random(ARange: Integer): Integer* and not the address of the other one.

Comment: I see. You wrote another function, called `Random` in it, and then exported that new function to your script.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

Compile:

```
psc.AddDelphiFunction('function Random(const ARange: Integer): Integer');
psc.AddDelphiFunction('function Random2: Extended');
```

Runtime:

```
type TRandom2 = function: Extended;
var Random2: TRandom2;

pse.RegisterDelphiFunction(@Random,'Random',cdRegister);
Random2:=Random;
pse.RegisterDelphiFunction(@Random2,'Random2',cdRegister);
```

I forced the "Random: Extended" with a type definition.